# C++ Circular Dependency in Header Files

Tags: c++, header-files, circular-dependency

Is it possible to avoid circular dependency in the following header files **without** turning data member **b1** in **class A** to a pointer/reference, and **without** relaxing the inline function requirement in **class B**?

A.h:

```
#ifndef A_H
#define A_H
#include <B.h> // Required, as data member b1 is not a pointer/reference

class A {
    public:
        B b1; // I want to keep this as as it is.
        int m_a;
};

#endif
```

B.h:

```
#ifndef B_H
#define B_H
#include <A.h> // Required, as f() calls a member function of class A

class B {
    public:
       int f(A &a){return a.m_a;} // I want this to be an inline function.
};

#endif
```

...and let's say main.ccp is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <A.h>
#include <B.h>

int main() {
    A a;
    B b;

    std::cout << "Calling b.f(a): " << b.f(a) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can't you just declare the function to be `inline` in the cpp file?

Comment: What do you think `#ifndef` does? lol, it will define it only once.

Comment: @dwcanillas I assume you are implicitly suggesting that that I delete `#include <A.h>` from **class B** and make a forward declaration there  instead. Let's suppose I did that. Then I would have to include **B.cpp** **everywhere** that I want the function to be inlined. Is there a way that doesn't require such duplications?

Comment: @Fallen The intention is to use it as a "header guard" to avoid multiple inclusions of the headers. Could you kindly be clearer if you are suggesting a solution?

Comment: The files get called, but it wont redefine the headers, hense the purpose of the header guard.   So, in main, A gets called from main, B gets called from A, A is attempted to be called from B but kicked back, return from the stack calls.  The files might get called, but after that first few, it wont redefine it anymore..  So you defined it, but it will not redefine them, no?   As a side note, what about using proper inheritance?  How can A and B inherit from eachother.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could use this:

A.h

```
#include <B.h>
#ifndef A_H
#define A_H

class A 
{
public:
    B b1;
    int m_a;
};

#endif // A_H
```

B.h

```
#ifndef B_H
#define B_H

class A;

class B 
{
public:
    int f(A &a);
};

#include <A.h>

inline int B::f(A &a)
{
    return a.m_a;
}

#endif // B_H
```

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <A.h> // these could be in any order
#include <B.h>

int main() 
{
    A a;
    B b;

    std::cout << "Calling b.f(a): " << b.f(a) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This technique is called 'forward declaration'. You are letting your compiler know that the class exists.

Comment: Every step blew up in my face with this language so far, so I am a bit nervous about an `#include` outside the header guard, but I see the point.

Comment: Unfortunately, the only way to get rid of `#include` outside guard is to make wrapper header `A_B.h` (with its own guard) which includes guard-less `A.h` and `B.h` in proper order and then use this wrapper everywhere. In order to further protect user from direct inclusion of these headers you may `#ifndef` wrapper guard macro `A_B_H` in these headers with `#error`.