# Cyclic dependency and inheritance compilation error on c++

Tags: c++, inheritance, c++14, circular-dependency, cyclic-dependency

I have a problem in C++ that involves circular dependencies and inheritance.

I have implemented the design in parts and I will use pesudocode to ilustrate where the problem happens.

The first part is:

```
//app.h

include rel.h

class Rel; // forward declaration

class App {
  shared_ptr<Rel> //member variable
}

//rel.h

include app.h

class App; //forward declaration

class Rel {
  shared_ptr<App> //member variable
}
```

Until here, the program compiles without warnings

Then, I want to add inheritance as follows:

```
//app.h

include rel.h
include drel.h

class Rel; // forward declaration
class DRel // forward declaration

class App {
  shared_ptr<Rel> //member variable
  shared_ptr<DRel> //member variable
}

//rel.h (the same as before)

include app.h

class App; //forward declaration

class Rel {
  shared_ptr<App> //member variable
}

//drel.h

include app.h
include rel.h

class App; //forward declaration

class DRel: Rel { // compile error here: expected class name before { token
  shared_ptr<App> //member variable
}
```

As you see, the compiler throws "expected class name before { token" which means that `Rel` is not resolved, but why the first code without inheritance works and the second one doesn't? How can I fix that? Is that a "wrong" pattern?

I am using c++14

I know there are a lot of questions regarding the issues I am having, but I can't find the answer to my specific problem. Maybe I don't see it...

Comment: Do your actual headers also not have include guards? If you forward declare `App`, you shouldn't also include `app.h` in `Rel`'s header, include it in `rel.cpp` instead.

Comment: Agreed with @Darhuuk. Try moving everything out of the split headers and into the same header and see if that improves things.

Comment: My guess is that the guards are identical, causing the second .h file not to get loaded. Would be easier if the actual code was posted

Comment: This is especially because the forward declaration of `App` in `drel.h` should not be needed. This points to the `#include`s not working as intended

Comment: @Darhuuk moving the includes to the implementation file worked! Can you please explain the reason? I am just starting with c++ but I have experience in Java and Scala, so I am trying to do "complicated" things

Comment: _I will use pesudocode_ so you only get pseudosoluitions.

Comment: why do you use pseudo-pseudocode? Seems like only minor changes could turn this into real code that would make a [mcve]. Sorry I dont get the point of writing `include app.h` instead of `#include "app.h"` just to make it non valid code

Comment: @vicaba: The whole point of using forward declarations is not having to include `app.h` in `rel.h`, because that in turn would then require `rel.h` to be included in `app.h` and there you go: cyclic includes. For a more thorough explanation, I suggest reading some SO questions on cyclic inclusion, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30223453/c-circular-dependency-in-header-files.

Comment: @Darhuuk: I understand the use of forward declaration. What I don't get is how moving the include to the implementation solved the problem. Is it because there where two definitions of the same symbol and the compiler didn't know which one to choose?

Comment: Apart from your main question - this way you can easily introduce a memory leak due to `std::shared_ptr` cyclic dependency. In one of your classes use `std::weak_ptr` instead.

Comment: @Ptaq666 Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Since all the variables you declare do not need to know the space occupied by App, Rel and DRel, you don't even need to `#include` the headers in question, you just have to forward declare the name as you do.

So you have you `.h` with

```
class A;
class B;

class C {
    std::shared_ptr<A> ptra;
    std::shared_ptr<B> ptrb;
};
```

And then your `.cpp` with

```
#include "A"
#include "B"

C::C()  { ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

The original headers files needed to be guarded by #ifdefs like this:

```
#ifndef CYCLIC_DEPENDECY_1
#define CYCLIC_DEPENDECY_1
#include "cyclic_dependency2.h"
class Rel; // forward declaration

class App {
   std::shared_ptr<Rel> test; //member variable
};
#endif




#ifndef CYCLIC_DEPENDECY_2
#define CYCLIC_DEPENDECY_2
#include "cyclic_dependency1.h"

class App; //forward declaration

class Rel {
   std::shared_ptr<App> test;//member variable
};
#endif



#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include "cyclic_dependency2.h"

class Rel; // forward declaration
class DRel; // forward declaration

class DRel: Rel { 
   std::shared_ptr<App> test ;//member variable
};

main()
{
}
```